# Undefined Error in Suite CRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

when user add element from toolbox undefined instant of new panel and new row. How to solve this error.

Screenshot :

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using correct `.htaccess`

Go to `Admin > Repair` and do a `"Quick Repair & Rebuild"`. Execute any changes shown at the bottom of the page.

If that doesn't work, go to `Admin > Repair` and do `"Rebuild .htaccess file"` and afterwards, `Admin > Repair` and do a `"Quick Repair & Rebuild"` again.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting inside the cache folder, check for cache folder permission in my case i change to 775, delte empty the .htaccess file (don't delete the file),go to admin ->repair->quick repair & built and also rebuilt .htaccess file, log out and try login again. Check config file for this value :

```
'default_permissions' => 
  array (
    'dir_mode' => 1528,
    'file_mode' => 493,
    'user' => 'daemon', -> check and change to your Apache user config
    'group' => 'daemon', -> check and change to your Apache  user Group
  ),
```

installation folder must be specified in the right location look for :

```
'site_url' => 'http://suitecrm.com', ->change to your url
```

https://suitecrm.com/suitecrm/forum/suitecrm-7-0-discussion/1137-undefined-text